# How to hide TexStudio splash screen

Tags: texstudio

I often use TexStudio and it is very satisfactory. However, the splash screen appeared when I start the app is very annoying. (What may I call this? Opening splash?) It continues to come in front when I tried to take it background.

I use macOS High Sierra. How could I disable(or hide) the splash screen? I checked all options, but there iss nothing about the splash screen.

If here is not right place to ask this, please let me know.

**EDIT**: I add the picture about what happened.

[image]

You can see cursor changed when I clicked the behind window.

Comment: Hi @ChoMedit and welcome to TeX-SE. I use TeXstudio since 2011, but on Windows. I'm sorry I don't know what you mean by "splash screen always come forward". To me, it appears only at the beginning. Could you add some images to your question?

Comment: @FHZ Thanks for welcoming. I edit my question. I didn't know the meaning "come forward" and misuse it, sorry. Anyway, I intend to explain the situation that the splash screen constantly reappears although I try to turn it off by clicking another window. I'll attach the image, but It may not be help for describing the situation.

Comment: I add the context when the splash appears, it is just the screen with TexStudio logo on the opening of the app.

Comment: I'm using  texstudio on ubuntu and the "splash screen" arises only at the start. It normally  disappears immediately when the application is ready. My suggestion is to remove and reinstall texstudio ?

Comment: @Piroooh Actually, my splash screen also arises only at the start. My question is, I want to disable the screen at the start, too.

Comment: Does it disappears when texstudio is launched or is it forever spawning ? Remove the starting windows to disable it at the start seems for me impossible. I'll looking for that.

Comment: @Piroooh It disappears when texstudio is launched. I think it's enough if it can be fixed on background. Disabling it is another option.

Comment: Now I got it. I would say it is a pretty common feature of many softwares, it is like "hey, we're loading, waiting a little bit, don't start the program 10 times". If the splash screen was always showing, that would be a very strange error/behavior. It might have some underground form to edit it, but (it is just an opinion here) it seems to be a lot of effort for too little return.

Comment: @FHZ Yes I agree that, and not to show up is actually not good option as you say. But at least, since it takes too long to disappear(loading is slow) it makes me a little annoying;I can't do anything until the app is well loaded. So, I just want to hide it if I want. I think it's enough to see the splash screen only when it appears for that purpose.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the settings, perhaps you should make a feature request at  https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues